# What extensions are there for generated C# files?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, file-extension

I'm writing a filter for the C# files that are generated, and want to get rid of the obvious generated files such as `.Designer.cs` or `.g.cs`. What other generated extensions are there? Thanks.

**Clarification:** I'm only looking files that have a `.cs` extension, but something comes before the `.cs`. Meaning that C# files that do not end in `.cs` do not interest me.

Comment: there are the .suo and .user if you are using VS

Comment: Things are going to break if you get rid of the `.Designer.cs` file. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just pay attention to what folder they are stored in.

Comment: you might want to consider giving some more context and explaining what you want to achieve by doing this - it may invite some more useful answers

Comment: Please mark as answered,based on which you find is the correct answer.This may help others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might be forgetting many of them, but still:

- *.baml
- *.g.cs
- *.g.i.cs
- *.designer.cs
- *.cache
- *.tlog
- *.g.resources
- *.cache
- *.lref
- *.pdb
- *.exe
- *.dll (Might well be some outside dll instead of being a generated one!)
- *.xml

I have only listed solution related extensions and not source control related extensions.

Comment: Service references: Reference.cs

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you source control you may have files like...

1. *.vspscc
2. *.scc
3. *.vss

If a WPF project then

1. *.xaml.cs

...

.resx ???

VS Files

1. *.user
2. *.suo